typescript narrowing down union type with two different properties?
I often face this issue when I deal with third party library. But I don't know how to solve this.
I created example code to explain what's the issue.
// thrid party function: I can configure the what type the detail is but I can't change implementation
const reply = (detail: { status: 400 } | { status: 403; cause: string }) => {
  return true;
};

// our code

type Param<S, C> = {
  status: S;
} & (C extends string ? { cause: C } : unknown);

const getDetail = <S, C>(param: Param<S, C>) => {
  return param;
};

const test1 = getDetail({ status: 400 } as const);
// { status: 400 } looks good!
const test2 = getDetail({ status: 403, cause: "no-permission" } as const);
// { status: 403, cause: "no-permission" } looks good!

reply(getDetail({ status: 400 }));
// Error:
// Argument of type '{ status: 400; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Param<400, string>'.
// Property 'cause' is missing in type '{ status: 400; }' but required in type '{ cause: string; }'.ts(2345)


Basically I like to write getDetail utility function. But it seems not resolving the type very well probably the Param type I wrote is not correct and TS can't find relationship between S and C to match to given parameter type of reply function.
Is there way to solve this?

"But it seems not resolving the type very well probably the Param type I wrote is not correct": Mind adding a bit more context? What is being provided and what is your expectation?

I mean as you see my comments in the code, when I check the return value, they look good. They're resolved well. If I put these result inline to reply, they're fine. But when using getDetail with reply, I get the error above (in the comment)

Status is treated as an OR.... { status: 400 } | { status: 403; cause: string }. cause is required in 403 case. You might want to change it to something like.... {status: 400 | 403, cause? string}? Reply doesnt satisfy both cases is the problem. The enforcement of cause: string is the main offender. It would need to be optional -- cause?: string. The as const though i would highly recommend against

What is the intention behind having two generic parameters here? Why not just a single one, T extends Reply (where type Reply = { status: 400 } | { status: 403; cause: string })? Or even just a non-generic function which accepts a parameter of the concrete type Reply?

Your getDetail accepts one parameter of the same type as the parameter of reply. That type is { status: 400 } | { status: 403; cause: string }. What is the problem if you just declare that as the type for getDetail's parameter?

@kaya3 let's say reply's parameter type is not always the same and configurable. So I want to write generic utility function for the circumstance. They can have status always but some of them can have "cause" prop too.

So how about a parameter of type {status: number, cause?: string}? Why does it have to be generic?

@kaya3 let's say they can be complex as well. e.g) { status: 400: cause: { reason: string} } | { status: 403; cause: number }

Same question, what's wrong with just making that the parameter type, and why does it have to be generic? Why does it need to have two generic parameters? I think there will be a straightforward answer, but what the answer is depends on how you need to use the function. If you need to be able to pass the result as the parameter to reply, a single generic T extends {status: number, cause?: unknown} should be enough.

@BrightLee in that case { status: number: cause: number | { reason: string} }. Try to find the common patterns. I'd argue cause would be the one generic you end up using though but I dont know your codebase

Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that motivates what you're doing. Prev comments here are correct that right now there's no good way to do this with two generic parameters, and that T extends some supertype of your detail will be good enough, as shown here. If that doesn't suffice, then we need more example code in the question that demonstrates what's lacking for you.

@kaya3 , Dom.  my goal is to find a way to write generic that checks cause type for each status. So that I can prevent not valid reply. Of course if I can do inline (object literal) there is no problem. But I like to know if there is way to solve this.

@jcalz thanks for your example. but const test3 = reply(getDetail({ status: 400, cause: 2 })); is also accepted which I like to prevent upfront.

Please [edit] to put that example in the question then, not just as a comment.  You can use {status: 400, cause?: never} to prohibit a property as shown here. Is that all this is about or am I missing something more?

@jcalz you're right. But I'm passing these schema definition to third party using Typebox (Json schema builder). So passing "never" is not ideal for my use case. But unless I use object literal, maybe it's not possible to prevent this, I guess?

• Again, if any of this is important for people answering your question, please [edit] these requirements into the question. It's true that you cannot generally prohibit excess properties (object literals are the only place TS even tries to), and it's not clear from the question why it matters. (pls acknowledge this request to edit, it's the 3rd one and I'm not sure it has been received). • If I really try to keep close to the original I get something like this approach but I'd love to see something in the question that motivates such complexity.

@jcalz I think I should write full code to explain better. Let me get back to you in a day. thanks.

@jcalz Hi, sorry it took long time to come back. this code snippet. This code could explain what I'm trying to do. But while I'm writing code snippet, I realized that taking cause out from my errorReply function seems the best, as everyone pointed out in the comments and asking why not using one generic parameter. There is a little loss when not using C second parameter (no auto-suggestion while writing param in errorReply. After writing, TS kicks in, though), but I think it would be ok...

Sorry, but I don't know anything about fastify and I'm not inclined to learn much about it to answer a pure TS question. Is the question dependent on fastify? If so please tag it as such so experts can see it. If not, please make sure your [mre] doesn't rely on it (you should be able to show motivation without pulling in third party libraries directly; any relevant types that are needed can be declared in your example code). And again, if any of this is important, please [edit] the question to mention it, don't just leave a comment. Comments can get deleted without a trace.

@jcalz You're right. Thanks again for your response!
